# How to disable the TextField of a JavaFx DatePicker?

Tags: javafx, java-8

I want to know how to disable the textfield of a JavaFx DatePicker? I was looking for this question and could not find it, so I am posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable the DatePicker's textfield you should get the editor and setDisable to true.

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
datePicker.getEditor().setDisable(true);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you still want the textfield to look normal (not grayed out) but still not editable, you can set the editor not editable:

```
datePicker.getEditor().setEditable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable the textfield and not have it greyed out you can do this:

```
DatePicker datePicker = new datePicker();
datePicker.getEditor().setDisable(true);
datePicker.getEditor().setOpacity(1);
```